# Omitting a specific field with CreateMany from AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I want to create "many" instances of foo :

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var expectedFoos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>();
```

The problem is, Foo is an Entity Framework entity, with relations that I don't want to create. If I needed only one instance, I could do that :

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var expectedFoo = fixture.Build<Foo>()
                         .Without(foo => foo.Relation1);
                         .Without(foo => foo.Relation2);
```

But how can I **easily** create multiple instances satisfying this condition ? I've read about specimen builders but it seems really overkill here.

I'm looking for something as simple as that (doesn't compile because `BuildMany` doesn't exist) :

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var expectedFoos = fixture.BuildMany<Foo>()
                          .Without(foo => foo.Relation1);
                          .Without(foo => foo.Relation2);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's what `Customize` is for:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<Foo>(o => o
       .Without(foo => foo.Relation1)
       .Without(foo => foo.Relation2));
var expectedFoos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `Customize` is definitely the right answer. However, just for the sake of [documentation](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#wiki-set-property), `Build` will work too:

```
var expectedFoos = fixture.Build<Foo>()
                          .Without(foo => foo.Relation1)
                          .Without(foo => foo.Relation2)
                          .CreateMany();
```